# Vim advanced multiline edits

Tags: vim

I'm trying to getting into using more advanced vim features.
How would people go about for the following edit?

from this:

```
ssn=token_payload.fnr,
fname=token_payload.displayName,
email=token_payload.email,
login=token_payload.username,
```

to this:

```
ssn=token_payload['fnr'],
fname=token_payload['displayName'],
email=token_payload['email'],
login=token_payload['username'],
```

Comment: You can use macros, simply start saving macro for `fnr`, and repat for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Command line :norm command

I would apply the following normal commands to all lines in the file:

```
" note that in the real command, <Esc> would be a literal 
" press of the escape key (see explanation below)

:%norm f.s['<Esc>f,i']
```

- apply to the whole file: `%`
- the following normal mode commands:`norm`
- move to the period: `f.`
- substitute with opening square bracket and quote: `s['`
- escape insert mode (press ctrl+v to enter a literal character, then escape -
  you'll see a gray symbol appear): `^[`
- move to the comma: `f,`
- insert the quote and closing square bracket: `i']`

I started using the command line way instead of macros recently since I find
that you can think it over more easily (particularly if you compose the command
in the command buffer with `q:` - see `:help command-buffer`).

#### Use a macro

Another way is to record a macro:

```
qa0f.s['<Esc>f,i']<Esc>jq
```

Which you can then deploy on the current line with `@a` and repeat with `@@`.
Or use `:%norm @a` to run the macro on each line.

It's basically the same as above, but instead of `:%norm` you use `qa` to
record into the `a` register (you can use any letter). Then perform the edit. I
added a drop down one line with `j` before stopping the recording with `q`.

You can edit the macro after recording it by pasting the contents of the
register (`"ap`), edit them, and yank them back (`"ay$`) before replaying it.

#### Using an external tool

If I wanted to perform multiple substitutions with a single command, I would
filter the text through an external program like sed:

```
:%!sed "s/\./['/; s/,$/'],/"
```

#### One more g[ood] thing

An extremely powerful tool is the `:g[lobal]` command! (see `:help :g`) I've
been using it a lot in combination with the `norm` command. For example, if I
wanted to get all the paragraphs in a document formatted nicely, but not affect
indented text (which could be code blocks, or tables etc.) I would do:

```
:%g/^\w/norm gqap
```

This means, for any line with a letter at the very start of the line, apply the
command `gqap` which applies the normal mode command `gq` to 'a paragraph'.

You might also want to capitalise the first word and increase the header level
of all the markdown headings like so:

```
:%g/^#/norm w~I#
```

This would change this:

````
# a heading
some text.

## another heading
some more text

```sh
    # and a comment in some code will be unaffected
    print('hello world')
```
## a further heading
some text

# conclusion
````

into this:

````
## A heading
some text.

### Another heading
some more text

```sh
    # and a comment in some code will be unaffected
    print('hello world')
```
### A further heading
some text

## Conclusion
````

see [these videos](http://derekwyatt.org/vim/tutorials/advanced) for 'advanced' vim stuff

Comment: Thank you for a great and very thorough answer :) I made it work with a macro first, but i will give :norm a shot now!

Comment: You're welcome - I'm at the same stage as you where I want to transition to all those cool methods making a lot of changes across lines efficiently. Have you seen these famous videos in the vim world: http://derekwyatt.org/vim/tutorials/advanced/

Comment: Great tip, ill check them out

Answer (score 3):

I'd implement this as an `:s` command.  For example, this command would make the requested changes:

```
:%s/\.\(.*\),/['\1'],/
```

That operates on all lines `%`, matches the dot and comma and puts everything in between into a group (`\(.*\)`), and then replaces it with the desired value, matching the first group (`\1`).

If you want to operate on a different set of lines, you can write `:1,4` instead of `:%`, or write `:'<,'>` to operate on the visual selection.

Comment: Nice use of the capture group in the substitution.

Comment: The `/g` is not necessary.